# How to fix broken bracket for glass shower door?

Tags: shower, bathroom-fixtures, door-frame, glass, sliding-glass-door

The bracket thing fell off the side of the door beside the hinge part. How do I fix it? I would appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Is that piece that broke off part of a hinge or just part of a seal?   It is probably proprietary to whoever manufactured the door and would require some searching to find.  It does not look like a common product easily found in any home store.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a shower screen seal as RMDman suggested. If the glass is actually a door and is fixed to the wall with a hinge, such that it easily moves to facilitate access to the shower, it should just be a case of removing the old one and buying a suitable replacement:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/shower-door-seal-replacement/s?k=shower+door+seal+replacement

Mine is just a friction fit. Measure the length and thickness of the glass to ensure a good fit. The replacements can usually just be cut to length so the glass thickness is the more critical measurement.

Comment: Note there are three different kinds of door seal.  The bottom one is called a "sweeper".  If you have a curb (most showers do) the sweeper should also have a deflector on the inside to guide water into the shower.   The hinge side will have a soft flap against the wall.  The handle side may be the same or may have a hard flap to act as a stop.    Make sure to buy the right one or buy a set.

Comment: It looks like your hinge is in the floor, and what fell off is a tiny piece of sweeper between the hinge and the wall.  As this answer says, these things are supposed to be friction-fit.  But for a tiny piece like this you might want to "help" it with a bit of clear silicone.    You might be able to re-use the one that fell off.   You will have to experiment.